# Level Rank System Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to make a Level Rank command using Firebase Realtime Database.
So, I'm having trouble locating a user's XP. Here is the code:

```
const value = await require('firebase').default.database().ref('Level/Guilds').once('value')
var entries = Object.entries(value.val());

enXP = entries.filter(o => o[1]["Users"] ? o[1]["Users"][1]["xp"] : 0);
enXP.sort((a, b) => b[1]["Users"][1]["xp"] - a[1]["Users"][1]["xp"]);
```

The Json file is something like this:

```
{
  "Level": {
    "Guilds": {
      "123412341234": {
        "Users": {
          "432143214321": {
            "xp": "0",
            "level": "0"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using Firebase's built-in methods to extract the data from the JSON, and only then switch to regular JavaScript sort.

So:

```
const value = await require('firebase').default.database().ref('Level/Guilds').once('value')

let userXP = [];
value.forEach((guild) => {
  guild.child("Users").forEach((user) => {
    userXP.push({ user: user.key, xp: user.val().xp });
  })
})
```

And then you can do the sorting/filtering on the resulting object.

---

The above snippet will leave you with an array like this:

```
[
  { user: "432143214321", xp: 11 },
  { user: "432143214322", xp: 42 },
  { user: "432143214323", xp: i }
]
```

You can then sort that with:

```js
let userXP = [
  { user: "432143214321", xp: 0 },
  { user: "432143214322", xp: 42 },
  { user: "432143214323", xp: 11 }
];


console.log(userXP.sort((a,b) => b.xp - a.xp));
```

Comment: So... Thanks! But I'm a bit lost after that.
I use map array to display the users, so I tried userXP.map on the code I already have, but it says on the console that userXP.map is not a function.
I don't know much about arrays yet.

Comment: userXP.map(([key, value], i) => `**${i + 1} ${client.users.cache.get(key) ? `${client.users.cache.get(key).tag}**` : "Unknown**"}\n**XP:** ${value["xp"] || 0}\n\n`).slice(page, num).join("")

Comment: The code in my answer did use any map. I now updated it to use an array, and show you how to sort it. Please start from my code, instead of your own, as its more idiomatic and I honestly find you object parsing quite hard to read. If you're having problems making the code in my answer work, please ask about how my code works - instead of going back to your original attempt.

Comment: I achieved! Thanks a lot for the help! :D
I just had a problem with my pagination system, but I managed to fix it. I plan on asking later about a better system of this.